# Doctrine2 many to many bidiretional doesn't work on both sides

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I have a problem with ManyToMany Bidrectional realtion in Doctrine2 (Symfony 2.8.*)

OWNER

```
class User
{

/**
 *  @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="UserGroup", inversedBy="users")
 *  @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_groups")
 */
private $groups;
```

INVERSE

```
class UserGroup
{
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="groups")
 */
private $users;
```

Tried different things found on Internet but updating on Group side by adding users doesn't work as it doesn't update.

I do update User object when Group is added

```
// method of User class
public function addGroup(UserGroup $group)
{
    $group->addUser($this);
    $this->groups[] = $group;

    return $this;
}
```

and still updating users on group side doesn't work

Comment: Can you explain "doesn't work" more, do you mean it doesn't save anything to the database or that it doesn't set the properties of the objects as expected?

Comment: it doesn't update 'users_group' table according to changes made on UserGroup side

Comment: Any you're sure you're persisting and calling flush correctly?

Comment: Controler's methods are generated by crud, all works but this one

Comment: You could have a look at this example https://gist.github.com/Ocramius/3121916  One difference I see it that you're not using the `add` method on `$this->groups` but I'm not sure if this makes a difference

Comment: went through, implemented in my code and still the same result, no update on UserGroup side

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED by my colleague. The only thing chagned is: ***mappedBy*** to ***inversedBy*** in class UserGroup

```
class UserGroup
{
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="groups")
 */
private $users;
```

no problems or complains on

```
doctrine:schema:update --force
```

error on

```
doctrine:schema:validate
```

but functionality works, there is update now on both sides now.